# How is Reservoir Sampling being used here?

Tags: java

I am solving a question on LeetCode, which is based on the concept of Reservoir Sampling (RS).  The question is:

> Given an array (that may contain duplicates), randomly output the index of a given target number.  The target number is guaranteed to exist in the array.
>   For e.g., if the input is: `{1,2,3,3,3}` and the target is `3`, then any of the indices `2`, `3` and `4` must be returned with equal probability.  Similarly, if the target is `1`, then the index `0` should be returned (obviously with probability of `1`).

The most upvoted code is as follows:

```
public class Solution {

    int[] nums;
    Random rnd;

    public Solution(int[] nums) {
        this.nums = nums;
        this.rnd = new Random();
    }

    public int pick(int target) {
        int result = -1;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if (nums[i] != target)
                continue;
            if (rnd.nextInt(++count) == 0)
                result = i;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

As I understand RS, we first select, say `n` numbers.  Then, when we select the next number, we need to select it with the probability, `1/(n+1)`.  How does:

```
rnd.nextInt(++count) == 0
```

select a number with the probability of `1/(n+1)`?  I understand we do a `++count` to make it `n+1`, but what happened to the numerator?  Why is it `rnd.nextInt()` instead of a simple `1`?

**Edit:** Question link [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/random-pick-index/description/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so we have this statement `rnd.nextInt(++count) == 0`

The first time we hit a target, `count` increments to 1 and the statement evaluates to

```
rnd.nextInt(1) == 0
```

which always returns true, because the argument 1 is an **exclusive** upper bound and the only possible value it may return is 0. At this point, the current index is set as the result, because we do not know if there are any more targets in the array.

The second time we encounter a target, `count` becomes 2 and the statement evaluates to

```
rnd.nextInt(2) == 0
```

and this one returns either 0 or 1. Hence, the index has a 50% chance to be selected as the result.

So there are two known targets in the array and both had a 50% chance to be set as the result. That the second target had this chance was obvious, but for the first target we can do a small calculation. It had a 100% percent chance to be chosen the first time the code hit the if-statement and the second time there was a 50% chance that the second target did **not** become the result (leaving a 50% chance that the first target remained as the result). These chances combined results in

```
first target as result = 100% x 50% = 50%
```

These steps can be repeated for more than 2 targets, but it makes the explanation a lot more complex. In the end, all *N* targets in the array have a *1/N* chance of being the result.

Comment: When you say, _It had a 100% percent chance to be chosen the first time the code hit the if-statement_, you mean the first iteration right?  And then in the second iteration, the second target had a 50% chance (leaving 50% for the first).

Comment: Yes, definitely.